# HTTP 302 (Redirect) in Paypal sandbox adaptive payment

Tags: paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I want to implement paypal adaptive payment for my Spring WebApplication in sandbox mode. I have submit the following HTML Form

```
<form name="paypalSubscriptionPreApprovalFrom" id="paypalSubscriptionPreApprovalFrom" action="https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay" method="GET">
<input name="cmd" id="cmd" type="hidden" value="_ap-payment" />
<input name="preapprovalkey" id="preapprovalkey" type="hidden" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
</form>
```

My redirect url is "http://www.testApp.com/teatApp/paypalSuccess. After payment success, paypal will redirect to my application, but i'm unable to receive response parameters. because paypal return nothing. How can i receive paypal adaptive payment response.

Thanks,
SENTHIL B